# Can't find a solution to a insert query and foreign key conflict ADO.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

### Here's the exception text

> Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK__Pedidos__idClien__74AE54BC". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "FB4D5206F5E37B80717CE8DC9CC0F063_CTS\SISTEMA DE GESTIÓN - ESCALANDRÚN\SISTEMA DE GESTIÓN -ESCALANDRÚN\BIN\DEBUG\ESCALANDRUN.MDF",
> tabla "dbo.Clientes", column 'idCliente'.
> Se terminó la instrucción.

### Tables that are involved and queries:

> Pedidos(child): idPedido (PK) (Identity), idCliente (FK), FechaPedido
>
> Clientes(parent): idCliente (PK) (Identity), other data
>
> INSERT INTO [Pedidos] ([idCliente], [Pedido_Fecha])
> VALUES (@idCliente, @Pedido_Fecha);

I'm tryin to insert data in Pedidos table and allways i get this exception.

### What i know:

*It seem to be that this exception is thrown when the referenced data in parent table doesn't exists (BUT IT DOES cheked with a simple select query in sqlmanagement studio).

*That i'm pretty new to SQL and ADO.NET

### What i don't understand

*Why the insert query fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that you are attempting to put a value in `Pedidos`, column `idCliente` that doesn't exist in `Clientes`, column `idCliente`.

Here's an example of what you're doing wrong:

**dbo.Clientes**

```
idCliente    other data
1            ....
2            ....
3            ....
```

**dbo.Pedidos**

```
idPedido    idCliente    other data
1           1            ....
2           1            ....
3           2            ....
4           2            ....
```

Now, that is all well and relational.  But if you were to do this:

```
insert into dbo.Pedidos(idCliente)
values(4)
go
```

You would get an error.  This is because `Clientes` doesn't contain an `idCliente` with a value of 4.  It's all about relational integrity.  A foreign key constraint will not let you just put any value in there.  It must match up with the what it represents.

Comment: Thanks Shark for your answer!!, it confirms what i was thinking. Now i think that maybe the problem is in >ClientesTableAdapter<. But here's the catch: when i make a 'preview data' in the dataset designer it shows correctly all the data ¿Why in run time it doesn't fill the ClientesTableAdapter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the data exists in Clientes, go back and check to make sure everything else is expected.

For example, verify that the value of @idCliente is as expected.  Verify that this INSERT statement is happening when are where you think it is, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've found the problem, read my answer, the problem was too amateur...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the idCliente in the table Clientes with the same Id that are you inserting in Pedidos.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've found the problem, read my answer, the problem was too amateur...

Answer (score 0):

**I've found the error:** When i made the call to the method in wich i use the insert query the parameter was declared as Int64 (Long in SQL) i gave to it an Int so the problem was that i missed a cast.
Ergo the idCliente will never appear because i've been giving the query a non existant IdCliente as all of you figured out.